# I get 'TypeError:: 'type' object is not iterable' when I use pandas.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file containing values of user's social media activity for 20 days I want to get the details of the user activity on Day 1
I did get it by using this piece of code

```
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)')

day1 = df['d'].dt.date[0]
df = df[df['d'].dt.date.eq(day1)] 

df = df.melt(['date_time','d']) 

df = df[df['value'].eq('Y')] 


d = df.groupby('variable')['date_time'].agg(list).to_dict()

for x,y in d.items():
   print(x,y)
```

when I print it this what I get on Google Colab notebook

```
Instagram [Timestamp('2020-08-23 04:19:05.637617'), Timestamp('2020-08-23 04:20:07.351783'), Timestamp('2020-08-23 04:21:09.069061')]
Facebook [Timestamp('2020-08-23 04:44:49.635657'), Timestamp('2020-08-23 04:45:51.402162'), Timestamp('2020-08-23 05:01:18.989306')]
```

Now when I run the same on my terminal using after saving it as python file I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 43, in <module>
    d=df.groupby('variable')['date_time'].agg(list).to_dict()

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Thare are same input data? Also pandas versions are same?

Comment: Pandas version is the same ```pandas 0.22.0```

Comment: and data are same?

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: I think I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

There was problem with pandas version, so for pandas 0.22 need change:

```
d=df.groupby('variable')['date_time'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

to:

```
d=df.groupby('variable')['date_time'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - There is no used `list` in another code?

Comment: @GlenVeigas - So code is complete? there is only only `list` in all code and it is in `d = df.groupby('variable')['date_time'].agg(list).to_dict()` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the only place where list is being used

Comment: @GlenVeigas - Last idea - if upgrade pandas and retart pc, maybe help. I hope...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223823/discussion-between-glen-veigas-and-jezrael).